# After upgrade to 10.10, mediawiki on postgres is broken

Tags: 10.04, 10.10, php, postgresql, mediawiki

I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 from 10.04.

90% of the upgrade was ok but my Ubuntu-apache2-postgres-8.4 - mediawiki1.16 
does not work anymore.

Is there a bug in the postgres client or in  php5 pg?

Comment: We'll need more detail, are there errors in the log? Does the page display something? Was there an error during upgrade? That sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

it is a bug in ubuntu php5

pg_last_error

see
http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-server-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg43679.html

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer to your question, taking into account that its you who knows the best about your problem. You may accept your own answer for your own question as well if you feel to do so.

Comment: One additional point, a stable release update has been issued that fixes the bug, so apply updates and the problem should be resolved. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/660227

Answer (score 0):

A search of Google revealed that you're not the only one having this issue, but I'm personally not aware of any specific issues. If you're using the machine as a webserver, then you shouldn't be using a pre-release on it anyway. It is much better to use a release that is known to be stable for a webserver.

Comment: I don't see a "pre-release" in this case.